# How to generate getters en mass using aspectj

Tags: java, aspectj

I have the following problem, I am wondering whether anyone knows a solution:

I would like to dynamically generate specially named getters for every private field in every subclass of a certain class using aspectj or some other similar bytecode manipulation tool.

I would like the names of the getters to be based on the corresponding field names, but I can settle for having one method taking a field name string and returning a value, as long as there is no reflection involved.

Comment: You know you can do this automatically in the source code in most IDE's, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/index.html)?  If you have access to the source and are just trying to save typing, than its [`@Data`](http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) annotation might be what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As in Matt's answer, I suggest you [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html).
Using the [@Getter, @Setter](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) annotations on the class level, corresponding getters/setters based on names of all the non-static fields will be generated at compilation.

Much better than annotating classes by hand is to use [static crosscutting](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if101/aspectj/aspectj1.0/doc/progguide/ch01s05.html) of AspectJ ([page in the official documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-declare.html)) to add those annotations globally.

Example for declaring @Getter and @Setter on each persistent Entity :

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public aspect EntityAspect {
    declare @type: @Entity * : @Getter;
    declare @type: @Entity * : @Setter;
}
```

It requires you either to have the source code, or to use compilation by aspectj on existing jar (instrumentation of an existing library).

Comment: Please be aware of some issues when combining [Lombok and AspectJ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26157868/1082681). I do not know if they are resolved by now.