# AspectJ Spring Boot catch method with boolean parameter

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I use aspectj and spring boot.
I am trying to log a message when a method(boolean value) is called. 
aspects are working in general, but my expression for catching must be wrong

it is working with (but is of cause catching every method):

```
    @Before("execution(* de.fhb..*(..))")
```

also working (catching with only one parameter)

```
    @Before("execution(* de.fhb..*(*))")
```

now the problem:

```
    @Before("execution(* de.fhb..*(boolean))")
```

or

```
    @Before("execution(* de.fhb..*(java.lang.Boolean))")
```

does not work. Any help? The mistake must be between execution(* de.fhb..*((*my error i think*))

here my files (getter && setter are generated with lombok):

pojo:

```
package de.fhb.showcase;

@Getter @Setter
public class Show {

    private String name;
    private boolean live;

    public void makeShowLive(boolean value) {
        live = value;
    }
}
```

aspect:

```
package de.fhb.aop;

import javax.inject.Named;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
@Named
@Log
public class CleanCodeAspect {

    @Before("execution(* de.fhb..*(..))")
    public void checkStyleBooleanParameter() {

        log.warning("You used a method with only one boolean parameter. "
                + "Refactor it into 2 methods with True, False at the end.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `java.lang.boolean`. I also doubt that creating to methods like `setLiveTrue()` or `setLiveFalse()` is clean code. It should be more functional like `enable()`/`disable()` or `show()`/`hide()`. But that could be just me.

Comment: java.lang.boolean gives me that error: warning no match for this type name: java.lang.boolean
[Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression and with the clean code i got this idea from http://www.planetgeek.ch/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Clean-Code-V2.1.pdf (Selector / Flag Arguments) it is only a simple example (not the standard logging, time tracing). but thx for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct, see and test for yourself without Lombok. I think the problem is Lombok interfering with AspectJ, maybe similar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157868/1082681) (follow the links there to learn more details). It might be another issue, but that would be my first bet.

Comment: I removed lombok from my pojo but it does not work with boolean. * work fine. Should i post the link to my github repo?

Comment: Yes, please. I tried with native AspectJ, not with Spring. I am not a Spring user normally.

Comment: got it working with the standard sample here https://github.com/svenhornberg/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-aop . I will look for the difference Named and Component wasnt the reason