# Codahale Metrics: using @Timed metrics annotation in plain Java

Tags: java, metrics, codahale-metrics

I am trying to add metrics to a plain Java application using codahale metrics. I'd like to use the @Timed annotation, but it is unclear to me which MetricRegistry it uses, or how to tell it which MetricRegistry to use. The application is a plain Java 8 application, built with Maven 3, no Spring, no Hibernate.

I can not find any documentation on how to implement @Timed in the dropwizard documentation: https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/

I've added these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When I use a programatic call to Timer, I can get reports because I know which MetricsRegistry is used:

```
static final MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();
private void update() throws SQLException {
  Timer.Context time = metrics.timer("domainobject.update").time();
  try {
    [...]
  } finally {
    time.stop();
  }
}
```

But when I use the much more elegant @Timed annotation, I have no idea which registry is used, and therefore I can not create a reporter, which means I can not get the metrics reported (I'm not even sure if this actually does anything):

```
@Timed(name = "domainobject.update")
private void update() throws SQLException {
    [...]
}
```

Please advise on how to make the @Timed and other Metrics annotations work in a regular Java application.

**Additional info:** The reason I am finding this strange is that I have added the Lombok framework and the @Slf4j annotations do work. I added Lombok as a dependency in the maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And I can use the @Sl4fj class annotation to add a logger to the class without cluttering up the member variables:

```
@Slf4j
public class App {
  public void logsome(){
    log.info("Hello there");
  }
}
```

So if that's possible by just adding a dependency, I reckon I am just missing a dependency or configuration to get the codahale @Timed annotation work, as described above.

(by the way, check out Lombok, it will make your life easier: http://projectlombok.org/ )

Comment: I think you will be out-of-luck without Spring AOP or manually setting up AspectJ to weave your classes.  This kind of thing only works with AOP, so you need something to provide that into your classes.  For example, Spring AOP uses JDK Proxies, CGLIB or AspectJ to achieve this

Comment: So AspectJ would be the way to go? How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Even more interesting: Why does @   Slf4j work for instance, and @ Timed does not? I'm not explicitly using AspectJ to get Slf4j working.

Comment: What do you mean @ Slf4j?  I'm not familiar with any annotation based AOP with slf4j

Comment: Check out the additional info.

Comment: You can fix by including this in your application class:  @Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<PayloadStorageConfiguration> bootstrap) {JmxReporter.forRegistry(bootstrap.getMetricRegistry()).build().start();}

Comment: @Rolf If you like Annotations Style and doesn't want to go with any frameworks. then there is still one way. you can write your own annotations processor. and perform your tasks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Long story short, you cannot use `@Timed` without some kind of AOP (be it Spring AOP or AspectJ).

A week or two ago, I also decided to add metrics to our project and chose AspectJ for this task (mostly because I used it in the past for similar purpose and because it allows for compile-time weaving while Spring allows only runtime via proxies).

You should be able to find all the necessary information and instructions here: https://github.com/astefanutti/metrics-aspectj.

As for Lombok, I guess they use built-in javac annotations processor:

> Another point of contention is the implementation of both the code supporting IDE integration as well as the javac annotation processor. Both of these pieces of Project Lombok make use of non-public APIs to accomplish their sorcery. This means that there is a risk that Project Lombok will be broken with subsequent IDE or JDK releases.

Comment: This seems like the way to get @ Timed working indeed, thanks, but now Lombok and AspectJ get into an argument in my buildcycle. AspectJ complains about the @Slf4j annotation. I have to figure out how to make them play nice.

Comment: Seems like Lombok and AspectJ are not always playing nice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903686/lombok-does-not-work-with-aspectj

Comment: Time for tough decisions. I tried to remove Lombok in favor of the @Timed annotation, but the AspectJ stuff is giving me such a hard time, and is so hard and uncomprehensible to debug, I've given up. It makes the project way more complex, and creates a bigger problem than the one it is solving. I did mark your answer as "answered" because it *is* the answer, it's just too big of a hassle for my little project (and my little brain). Hand-coding the calls to Codahale Timers now. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use [`metrics-cdi`](https://github.com/astefanutti/metrics-cdi) in a cdi environment.

Comment: I would try looking at *InstrumentedResourceMethodApplicationListener*, as this is how metrics-jersey2 is implemented. It favors reflections over AOP. It won't be suitable for situations where you have no mechanism for executing code before and after method invocations (like you would have on request handling flows, as in Jersey).

Answer (score 12):

Using `@Timed` doesn't actually require the use of AOP, as was previously claimed in the top-rated answer, if you're inside a container and using one of Dropwizard's instrumentation libraries. See the Jersey 2.x module for example, which you can see uses reflection (as do the others I looked at), if you read the [source](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/tree/3.2-development/metrics-jersey2).

You can read up on all of these modules in [the Dropwizard docs](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/) under the corresponding "*Instrumenting ____*" bullets.

I understand the OP was explicitly NOT working within such a container, but I wanted to offer this info, since many of us looking for this answer may be working on a modern web service that can register such resources in its runtime environment.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answer stated, you have to have something in the application to listen for your instantiated classes and check them for the @Timed annotation.

If you're using Guice, you could use: https://github.com/palominolabs/metrics-guice

Comment: We used this in our production systems. This is useful.

Answer (score 5):

> Use the built-in MetricRegistry accessed from the bootstrap parameter in the initialize method of your application class.

```
@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<Configuration> bootstrap) {
    final JmxReporter reporter = JmxReporter.forRegistry(bootstrap.getMetricRegistry()).build();
    reporter.start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> AOP is overkill and not appropriate for use of @timed, generally
>   speaking.

The default metrics registry writes @timed metrics to a ConcurrentHashMap and does not attach any meaningful listeners.

DropWizard Bootstrap constructor:

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@link Bootstrap} for the given application.
 * @param application a Dropwizard {@link Application}
 */
public Bootstrap(Application<T> application) {
    this.application = application;
    this.objectMapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper();
    this.bundles = Lists.newArrayList();
    this.configuredBundles = Lists.newArrayList();
    this.commands = Lists.newArrayList();
    this.validatorFactory = Validators.newValidatorFactory();


    // returns new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Metric>(); 
    this.metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry(); 


    this.configurationSourceProvider = new FileConfigurationSourceProvider();
    this.classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    this.configurationFactoryFactory = new DefaultConfigurationFactoryFactory<T>();
}
```

> So you need to build/start/register the appropriate metric registry in
>   order to see results.

Here I use JMX:

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<PayloadStorageConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    JmxReporter.forRegistry(bootstrap.getMetricRegistry()).build().start();
}
```

That's all you need to do.

Here's an example of the output (run jconsole against your Java application/server to view JMX results):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this simple/right-to-the-point example https://karollotkowski.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/api-endpoint-in-one-minute-with-dropwizard/ just showed it only need the annotation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use stagemonitor-core for that. See documentation [here](https://github.com/stagemonitor/stagemonitor/wiki/Integrate-stagemonitor-into-non-servlet-based-applications) and [here](https://github.com/stagemonitor/stagemonitor/wiki/Track-your-own-metrics#declarative-annotation-based). The advantage is that stagemonitor (which is free & open source btw) does not depend on any container-based AOP like Spring AOP or EJB interceptors. It uses bytecode manipulation via runtime attachment which means that you do not even have to add a `-javaagent` flag to your application startup - a plain dependency is enough.

If you want to measure the execution time in a web application or in a remote EJB application, you don't even have to manually annotate your code. Also, stagemonitor offers preconfigured Grafana and Kibana dashboards.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of stagemonitor

Answer (score 0):

In newer Dropwizard versions (I am using 0.9.2), you can access the default `MetricRegistry` through the setup environment `io.dropwizard.setup.Environment`. This default `MetricRegistry` already has an `InstrumentedResourceMethodApplicationListener` associated with it, which listens to all the metrics of your resources.

If you have registered a resource with the `JerseyEnvironment` as under,

```
environment.jersey().register(resource);
```

you need only annotate your resource method (or class) with `@Timed`, `@Metered` or `@ExceptionMetered` to register the respective metrics.

```
@POST
@Timed
public String show() {
    return "yay";
}
```

You can assign a `Reporter` (like an `Slf4jReporter` or `JmxReporter`) to the default `MetricRegistry` as under

```
Slf4jReporter.forRegistry(environment.metrics()).build();
```

As a quick test to see if your metrics have actually been registered, you can make a `GET` call to the URL `http://localhost:8081/metrics` or the corresponding Admin Metrics URL in your test environment.

Some other versions require you to explicitly register an `InstrumentedResourceMethodApplicationListener` as shown [in this Doc](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/jersey/)