# Registration of @Timed and @Metric annotation on Metric Registry

Tags: java, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I was using the Metric annotation *@timer* and *@metrics* as instructed from the project, https://github.com/astefanutti/metrics-aspectj. Where will this metrics be registered in any Metric registry?I want to know whether this will be registered and how can i view it? Will these can be viewed in Jconsole or JMXreporter of DropWizard metrics.Is there any sample examples on the usage of it,if anyone can attach some samples it will be really helpful?Also  can anyone help me in adding the metrics-aspectJ plugin in *gradle.build* version 2.3

I viewed  a stackflow of a similar question [Codahale Metrics: using @Timed metrics annotation in plain Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499621/codahale-metrics-using-timed-metrics-annotation-in-plain-java?answertab=active#tab-top)
They mentioned about including metrics-aspectj but noting about how metrics registration was done.I was new to the Concepts of aspect orient programming. If anyone can explains how it works for the above github project, it would be great.

Comment: This could be useful to introduce own custom annotations like @IPCount, what can simply count the different client IPs since last hour or sth else. Someone here to explain how the annotation works, so that we can build our own metric annotation?