# Gradle + RoboBinding with AspectJ + Lombok are not compatible together

Tags: android, gradle, aspectj, lombok, robobinding

I want to integrate in Android project on Gradle following  libraries:

- Lombok
- RoboBinding with AspectJ
- Dagger

In order to use RoboBinding with AspectJ and android tools 1.1.0 I compiled aspectj-plugin with this [fix](https://github.com/kennyjoseph/RoboBinding-aspectj-plugin/commit/0f395808c6697513df4df8651a5c04ef5268dd9d).

All libraries are using some compile time annotation processing. I found that Lombok isn't compatible with AspectJ. I noticed that annotation processor from RoboBinding is using apt whereas lombok works only with provided (Dagger works with both).

I found also [Lombok and AspectJ](https://palesz.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/howto-maven-lombok-and-aspectj-together/) workaurond for Maven but I don't know if this can be used with Gradle too (if yes I don't know how to do it).

Without Lombok project is compiling and working. Can you help with integrating Lombok and AspectJ with Gradle?

**Error:**

```
Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
:app:compileDebugAspectJ
warning You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
Your processor is: org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchProcessingEnvImpl
Lombok supports: sun/apple javac 1.6, ECJ
error at model.setOutput(model.getInput());

D:\Projects\BinderExample\app\src\main\java\foo\binderexample\MainActivity.java:32:0::0 The method getInput() is undefined for the type BinderModel
Error:Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
Note: Start RoboBinding annotations processing...
error at model.setOutput(model.getInput());

D:\Projects\BinderExample\app\src\main\foo\binderexample\MainActivity.java:32:0::0 The method getInput() is undefined for the type BinderModel
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAspectJ'.
> The method getInput() is undefined for the type BinderModel
```

**Module:**

```
@Module(injects = MainActivity.class)
public class BinderModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    BinderModel provideBinderModel() {
        return new BinderModel();
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
@Data
@PresentationModel
public class BinderModel implements HasPresentationModelChangeSupport {

    private final PresentationModelChangeSupport changeSupport = new PresentationModelChangeSupport(this);

    private String input;
    private String output;

    @Override
    public PresentationModelChangeSupport getPresentationModelChangeSupport() {
        return changeSupport;
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject
    BinderModel model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ObjectGraph.create(new BinderModule()).inject(this);
        View view = Binders.inflateAndBind(this, R.layout.activity_main, model);
        setContentView(view);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    void onButtonClick() {
        model.setOutput(model.getInput());
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:bind="http://robobinding.org/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text"
        bind:text="${input}"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        bind:text="{output}"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Gradle script:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'org.robobinding:aspectj-plugin:0.8.3-fix'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.robobinding.android-aspectj'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "foo.binderexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'

    //dagger
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'

    //lombok
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.2'
    apt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.2'

    //robobinding
    compile('org.robobinding:robobinding:0.8.9:with-aop-and-dependencies') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    }
    aspectPath('org.robobinding:robobinding:0.8.9:with-aop-and-dependencies') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    }
    apt 'org.robobinding:codegen:0.8.9'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more about the situation of Lombok in combination with AspectJ, please read [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157868/1082681) and also follow the links there.