# Using aspectj in Hibernate entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have entity class like this:

```
package tr.com.example.model.porting
...//omitting imports

    @Configurable
    @Data
    @Entity
    public class PortOut{

      public void handleRequest(Long portingId) {
          processRequest(portingId);
           ...
        }
     }
```

And here is my aspect code in different class annotated with @Aspect and @Component:

```
 @Around("execution(* tr.com.example..PortOut.handleRequest(..))")
    public void handlePortingProcessAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        joinPoint.proceed();
        log.debug(log.debug("[POM]:{} is executed with parameters:{}", joinPoint.toShortString(), joinPoint.getArgs()))
    }
```

Normally, ***my aspect code works fine*** for other Spring managed classes such as using @Service, @Component annotation. I am using https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-instrument as a weaving agent and also using ***Lombok***.

I tried [this](http://www.baeldung.com/aspectj) link(along with other so posts). But since I am using Lombok, I cannot directy compile with aspectj compiler for weaving @Configurable classes, it doesn't work with Lombok as I found out.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/ZkLsTZVSgD4

***Shortly, what I want is using aspectj for logging some methods's arguments, but I can't use it in any Hibernate entity class, other than that it works fine. How to get it working in entity classes?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157868/1082681) you find the explanation why Lombok and AspectJ do not like each other.

What is [said to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487910/1082681) though, is to [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) the Lombok-annotated source code and then normally compile the generated source code with the AspectJ compiler (e.g. via [AspectJ Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/), which is what I use all the time in Maven projects). Assuming you do use Maven, also the delombok step can be done with [Lombok Maven plugin](http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/). If you assign the right phases to the respective plugins, it should be possible to fully automate the build process.

*Disclaimer: I have never used Lombok in my whole life, but know a thing or two about AspectJ and Maven.*

Comment: Consider using  Load-Time Weaving : so far it the only way to work with both Lombok and AspectJ