# AOP cut module from another module using aspectj-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I create a apring-boot project which has two module test-aop and test-web. I have upload this project in github https://github.com/zhxjouc/test .In test-aop, I define some AOP class and I want it cuts the test-web module. And I think the codes might be OK, but the aspectj-maven-plugin might be not work. I tried to modify the configuration for all day but it still not work. The following is the error while run `mvn clean install`

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.9:compile (default) on project test-web: AJC compiler errors:
abort ABORT -- (RuntimeException) Problem processing attributes in com/test/aop/TestLogAspect.class
Problem processing attributes in com/test/aop/TestLogAspect.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem processing attributes in com/test/aop/TestLogAspect.class
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:387)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.<init>(BcelObjectType.java:162)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.buildBcelDelegate(BcelWorld.java:410)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:487)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:453)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addAspectsFromJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:263)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:236)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:874)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:249)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AbstractAjcCompiler.execute(AbstractAjcCompiler.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad WeaverState.Kind: -115.  File was :<Unknown>::0
    at org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverStateInfo.read(WeaverStateInfo.java:170)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.AjAttribute.read(AjAttribute.java:105)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.readAjAttributes(Utility.java:101)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:383)
    ... 36 more
```

Here is pom configurations and I really want to where is the error. Please help me.

pom in test-group(parent)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-group</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>test-aop</module>
    <module>test-web</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <aspectjweaver.version>1.8.9</aspectjweaver.version>
    <aspectjrt.version>1.8.9</aspectjrt.version>
    <compiler.version>1.8</compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.version}</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

pom in test-aop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>test-group</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>test-aop</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

pom in test-web

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-group</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>test-aop</module>
    <module>test-web</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <aspectjweaver.version>1.8.9</aspectjweaver.version>
    <aspectjrt.version>1.8.9</aspectjrt.version>
    <compiler.version>1.8</compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.version}</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: If you use Spring, what is the reason for you to use the AspectJ compiler at all? For the simple use case "Spring component method interception" proxy-based Spring AOP is sufficient.You have not shown any aspect and application code, that is why I am asking. Before we try to solve an AspectJ Maven problem let us make sure you actually need the plugin at all.

Comment: @kriegaex It's my mistake. Before I create this project. I found some example which use this plugin, so I just create my project according those example， though I'm not very clear about it. It's my mistake. After I comment the aspecj-maven-plugin in my pom, it really work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, I have created an answer from my comment. You cann accept it in order to close the question.

Comment: @kriegaex I have accepted your answer. But do you have any idea about that exception?

Comment: I just cloned your repo and performed a build. No errors on my console. The application even runs with the /test endpoint. Now when I reactivate your commented-out AJ Maven plugin, I do see an error message, but it says: `NoSuchMethodError: com.test.aop.TestLogAspect.aspectOf()` IMO the root cause is several line further up, though: `[WARNING] You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
Your processor is: org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchProcessingEnvImpl`.

Comment: So the problem is the combination of Lombok + AspectJ, described by me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26157868/1082681) in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Spring, what is the reason for you to use the AspectJ compiler at all? For the simple use case "Spring component method interception" proxy-based Spring AOP is sufficient. You have not shown any aspect and application code, that is why I am asking. Before we try to solve an AspectJ Maven problem let us make sure you actually need the plugin at all.